# How to copy data from one table to another “EXCEPT” one field Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

How can I use codeigniter to copy all data of table1 to table2 except the primary key of table1. table1 and table2 have the same structure.

I try this :

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table1',array('patient_id'=>$this->input->post('patient_id')));
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
$this->db->insert('table2',$row);
}
```

It works but the primary key of table1 is inserted as well.

How can I ignore the primary key on table1 ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove `id` from `$row` with `unset($row->id);` where `id` is the column name of the primary key.

Comment: thanks for you reply. Must I put your codes just after $this->db->insert('table2',$row); ? Or where should I locate your codes ?

Comment: Before your insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming patient_id is the primary key in question, you can remove the data from the result object with `unset`.

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table1',array('patient_id'=>$this->input->post('patient_id')));
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    unset($row->patient_id);
    $this->db->insert('table2',$row);
}
```